# Matching Multiple Rows from a SubQuery into the main query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery

I would like to match multiple rows (exclusively) from a table to another table, and only return the rows that match ALL. Here is my example:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (Gr int, Dim char(1), Val int)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1,'A',10)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1,'B',200)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1,'B',201)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1,'B',202)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1,'C',22)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1,'C',23)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1,'C',24)

DECLARE @T2 TABLE (eDim char(1), eVal int)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('B', 200)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('C', 29)

SELECT T1.Gr, T1.Dim, T1.Val FROM @T1 T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @T2 T2 WHERE T2.eDim = T1.Dim AND T2.eVal = T1.Val)
```

In the example above, the query returns one row from T1 corresponding to the B-200 value pair. What I really need is to either return two records when both B and C values match T2, or return nothing if one or more of the records to not match. Something like "WHERE EXISTS ALL" but this is not recognized by SQL SERVER.

Comment: So you want to join with both "Dim" and "Val" column or just "Dim" column? From your example only one row would match.

Answer (score 0):

One to do it

```
SELECT Gr, eDim Dim, eVal Val
  FROM
( 
  SELECT T1.Gr
    FROM @T1 t1 JOIN @T2 t2
      ON t1.dim = t2.edim
     AND t1.val = t2.eval
   GROUP BY t1.gr
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @T2
  )
) q CROSS JOIN @T2
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27285)** demo *Try to uncomment last `INSERT INTO @T1` and run query again*

or

```
SELECT gr, dim, val
  FROM
(
  SELECT gr, dim, val, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY gr) cnt
      FROM @T1 t1 JOIN @T2 t2
        ON t1.dim = t2.edim
       AND t1.val = t2.eval
   GROUP BY gr, dim, val
) q
 WHERE cnt = 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @T2
)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27291)** demo *Try to uncomment last `INSERT INTO @T1` and run query again*

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?